# Grid elements to be sticky in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, grid, sticky

i have a weird situation that is happening only inside of a wordpress site installation. where i need to have a two columns grid and being the first one a sticky one on the top.

You can check the test page at: https://dev.mentepresente.pt/test/

the css is super simple and it works out of wordpress:

```
.wrapper {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50px 200px;} 

.item1 {
grid-column: 1;
align-self: start;
position: sticky;
top: 0;}


.item2 {
grid-column: 2;}
```

Does any one know the reason why this is happening?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was because i had a parent element with overflow: hidden; that was messing up with with the sticky position